# XML - "Invalid XML Document."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I am trying to update google contact. 
When i hit http request with below xml body, i am getting error 
"Invalid XML Document."

Below is my XML request.

```
 "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n
    <entry>\n
      <category scheme=\"https://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind\" term=\"https://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact\"/>\n
      <title>test Sun  1:00pm Kinjal S</title>\n
      <gd:name>\n
        <gd:fullName>test Sun  1:00pm Kinjal S</gd:fullName>\n</gd:name>
      <gd:phoneNumber label=\"Mobile\" primary=\"true\">+6598765432</gd:phoneNumber>
      <gd:phoneNumber label=\"Father\">+6598732465</gd:phoneNumber> 
      <gd:phoneNumber label=\"Friend\">+6589898989</gd:phoneNumber> 
      <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted=\"false\" href=\"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/paresh.tps@gmail.com/base/6\"/>\n
    </entry>"
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the 2 namespaces `gd` and `gContact` is not defined. I just added the namespaces and it seems good. Here is the modified XML with dummy namespaces (Please correct it accordingly),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry
    xmlns:gd = "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
    xmlns:gContact = "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
    <category scheme="https://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="https://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
    <title>test Sun  1:00pm Kinjal S</title>
    <gd:name>
        <gd:fullName>test Sun  1:00pm Kinjal S</gd:fullName>
    </gd:name>
    <gd:phoneNumber label="Mobile" primary="true">+6598765432</gd:phoneNumber>
    <gd:phoneNumber label="Father">+6598732465</gd:phoneNumber>
    <gd:phoneNumber label="Friend">+6589898989</gd:phoneNumber>
    <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/paresh.tps@gmail.com/base/6"/>
</entry>
```